# Can I rely on CDs and DVDs for storage when I copy them without errors?

Tags: windows, dvd, compact-disc, checksum

I have old CD and DVDs. I am copying the files I have on these discs to my hard drive, but can I be sure that these files are not broken? I copy these files with no errors and don't want to keep the CDs.

Should I keep the originals just in case the copied files are broken or does a successful copy operation mean that the copied files are not broken?

Comment: Successful copy means file is fine probably about as much as the file being unbroken before the cd/dvd was burnt.

Comment: I would recommend you after you finish to copy the files, to find a box, put in all your CD's, close the box thoroughly and put it somewhere in a dry place in the basement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OS standard file functions show no errors, you can be sure (on Data CDs/DVDs) that you have a correct copy, as all Data CDs have checksums and error correction data to reconstruct defective sectors to a certain amount.

Audio CDs however have a far less effective error correction, wich is usually ok, since small error aren't usually really audible.

You should however be aware, that CD-Rs / DVD-Rs have a relatively short lifespan ( 5-10 years) and DVD-Writer quality is not that good as it was 10 years ago. 
So you should backup important data minimum on 2 different DVD brands, because I also experienced that certain brands are less reliable or they had problems with a production charge.